# How to solve nonlinear constrained optimization in Matlab?

Tags: optimization, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I have to solve a nonlinear constrained function in matlab, and I am not familiar with it's commands.
the problem is:
**minimize** $E(b,c)$
constraints: $k1< c\sqrt{b}< k2 ;  c/6>k3$
Note: E(b,c) is a nonlinear function.

Also how can I solve this easier one
**minimize** $E(b,c)$
constraints: $c \sqrt{b} =k2;c/6>k3$
for simplicity imagine: i.e. $E(b,c)=b^{2}+ \sqrt{c}+c$ and $k1=8,k2=12,k3=5$
I must use Matlab mfile. Please suggest me what should I do!
I would like to plot the $E(b,c)$ based on given constraints and find the $b,c$ pairs, if that is possible.
I am not sure if I really need optimization toolbox or not.
Please give me a short Matlab script if it's ok.
thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/constrained-optimization.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider to use the external library [Yalmip](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/pmwiki.php?n=Tutorials.Tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SolvOpt](http://imsc.uni-graz.at/kuntsevich/solvopt/content.html) code based on Shor's iterative method. For more information, see the original [paper](https://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1023/A:1008739111712).